# how to interpret ptx function names

Tags: cuda, nvcc, ptx

when I compile my cuda file:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_61 -std=c++11 -Xptxas -v,-warn-spills --use_fast_math -maxrregcount 128 nv_wavenet_perf.cu -o nv_wavenet_perf_dual
```

I get many lines of register spill warnings:

```
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function '_Z25nv_wavenet_singleBlock_8RIffLi64ELi256ELi256ELi1EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E'
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function '_Z25nv_wavenet_singleBlock_8RIffLi64ELi256ELi256ELi2EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E'
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function '_Z25nv_wavenet_singleBlock_8RIffLi64ELi256ELi256ELi3EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E'
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function '_Z25nv_wavenet_singleBlock_8RIffLi64ELi256ELi256ELi4EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E'
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function '_Z20nv_wavenet_dualBlockIffLi64ELi256ELi256ELi1EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E'
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function '_Z20nv_wavenet_dualBlockIffLi64ELi256ELi256ELi2EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E'
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function '_Z20nv_wavenet_dualBlockIffLi64ELi256ELi256ELi3EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E'
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function '_Z20nv_wavenet_dualBlockIffLi64ELi256ELi256ELi4EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E'
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function '_Z25nv_wavenet_singleBlock_8RIffLi64ELi128ELi256ELi1EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E'
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function '_Z25nv_wavenet_singleBlock_8RIffLi64ELi128ELi256ELi2EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E'
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function '_Z25nv_wavenet_singleBlock_8RIffLi64ELi128ELi256ELi3EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E'
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function '_Z25nv_wavenet_singleBlock_8RIffLi64ELi128ELi256ELi4EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E'
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function '_Z20nv_wavenet_dualBlockIffLi64ELi128ELi256ELi1EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E'
ptxas warning : Registers are spilled to local memory in function '_Z20nv_wavenet_dualBlockIffLi64ELi128ELi256ELi2EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E'
...
```

1. How can I tell what function is spilling, since the function name presented here are not identifiable for me.
2. I only want to see spillage for "dualBlock" functions. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I tell what function is spilling, since the function name presented here are not identifiable for me.

CUDA uses the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/). What you see are standard g++ style mangled function names. Every host toolchain ships with a demangler which can parse mangled function names (c++filt is most typical). There are even [online](https://demangler.com/) demanglers. They will demangle function names. Internal CUDA ABI symbol demangling is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39249151/681865) AFAIK.

For example:

```
_Z20nv_wavenet_dualBlockIffLi64ELi128ELi256ELi2EEv17nv_wavenet_paramsIT_T0_E
```

demangles to

```
void nv_wavenet_dualBlock<float, float, 64, 128, 256, 2>(nv_wavenet_params<float, float>)
```

> I only want to see spillage for "dualBlock" functions. Is this possible?

Those warnings are generated by `ptxas`, the assembler. There is no way I am aware of to make those warnings selective. They are either on or off. If you separately compile a certain function, it might be possible to control the level of output from the assembler for that invocation, but not function by function within a single compilation call, as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 0):

As a minor update to the accepted answer:

Q1) nvidia now provides a binary 'cu++filt' for demangling offline on the CLI.

Q2) if you only want to "see" a subset of warnings, you could always redirect stdin/err to a file and do a simple grep (I'm sure there are better ways to parse everythin.)

```cpp
grep ptxas my_make_output.txt | grep dual
```